# distance measuring from ultrasonic sensor, variable overflow

Tags: c, avr, robotics

Hy, I have ultrasonic sensor measuring distance and no mather which type is my variable "range"  (uint8_t, uint16_t, 32, 64)I always get overflow, and than sensor starts from 0 again..Is there a way that I can limit "range" variable or I must limit that on harder way with pulsewidth... Thanks

```
SENSOR_DDR |= (1<<TRIGGER_PIN);  
SENSOR_DDR &= ~(1<<ECHO_PIN) & ~(1<<PB3) & ~(1<<PB2) & ~(1<<PB1) & ~(1<<PB0); 
DDRD = DDRD | _BV(4); 
PORTD = PORTD | _BV(4);
ENGINE_DDR = 0xff; 
ENGINE_PORT = 0;

lcd_init(LCD_DISP_ON);
lcd_clrscr();
lcd_puts("Something wrong...");


while(1)
{

PORTB |= (1<<PB4); //Send Trigger
_delay_us(10);
PORTB &= ~(1<<PB4); //Send trigger


timer0counter=0;
TCNT0=0; //Clear timer
while(bit_is_clear(PINB,5)); //Wait for rising edge
TCCR0 |= (1<<CS02); //Select prescalar 256
TIMSK |= (1<<TOIE0) | (1<<TOIE2); //Enable timer0 overflow interrupt

lcd_clrscr();

while(bit_is_set(PINB,5) && timer0counter<9) //wait for falling edge of echo
{
_delay_us(5);
}
TCCR0 &= ~(1<<CS02); //Stop timer
TIMSK &= ~(1<<TOIE0);
if(bit_is_set(PINB,5))
{
lcd_puts("No OBSTACLE");
}
else
{
range=(256*timer0counter+TCNT0)*32*0.017; //range conversion

lcd_clrscr();
lcd_puts("Distance:");
lcd_puts(itoa(range,buffer,10));
lcd_puts_P("cm");
}
if(range<15){
...

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) 
{
TIMSK &= ~(1<<TOIE0);
TCNT0=0;
timer0counter++;

TIMSK |= (1<<TOIE0);

if(timer0counter>8)
{
TCCR0 &= ~(1<<CS02);
TIMSK &= ~(1<<TOIE0);

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific of how you acquire data from the sensor.

Comment: now I added some code I hope it helps you so you could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation

```
256*timer0counter+TCNT0
```

saves temporary value in 'default' size int, which on AVR is 16b. so, every time timer0counter is higher than 256 it will overflow regardless of the final type of the variable.

instead of doing

```
range=(256*timer0counter+TCNT0)*32*0.017;
```

try going with:

```
double range_real = 256.0 * (double)timer0counter + (double)TCNT0 * 32.0 * 0.017;
range = (int) range_real;
```

Being explicit about types can really save your skin.

Comment: but now when I think again....my variable timer0counter only counts until in timer0 TCNT0 register comes to overflow and this is 255....so timer0counter is a variable which cannot overflow really...TCNT0 can but this is ok that's why I multiply number of overflows (timer0counter) with 256 (timer 0 register TCNT0)...

Comment: I don't know if I understand the your problem correctly.
I'm just pointing out, that when running multiplication of ints, the result is also an int, which on AVR may store numbers between -32k and + 32k. Which is not a lot :)
You run (256*timer0counter+TCNT0)*32... This is like if you consider 32k being the maximum, (256*timer0counter+TCNT0) have to be smaller than 1k, so in turn timer0counter has to be smaller than 4...

Comment: so, timer0counter is a variable that increments itself every time when  TCNT0 (timer 0 register) overflows. and variable timer0counter can't overflow..

Comment: Ok. So if TCNT is for instance 100, and timer0counter is 5. The calculation is as follows: 256*5 + 100, which is 1380; then you multiply it by 32 and the result becomes 44160, which will not fit into integer and you get ugly (wrong^^) value (probably -24576) and then you multiply it by a 0.017 (which is of type double), and you get something around -417.xx (which is again double).

Comment: There are few calculations you do in that one line. They are not all done at once. Every operator (like '*' and '+') is run only on two arguments, and result of that operation has to be stored somewhere (even though you only use for further computation). There are also limits for those intermediate variables (the same one as for ordinary variables).

Comment: aha...yeah you are right, I wasn't even thinking that way :S
thanks one more time :)

Comment: Please remember to up vote posts/answers/comments that you find useful. It's the best way to show appreciation! :)

Comment: I intendent to but my reputtion is too low :/